# Skype virtual camera mirrored image

Tags: c++, windows, directshow, skype

I've [asked a same question on MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/8742ce98-e0d1-4ef6-93e0-4aba0da844fb/skype-virtual-camera-mirrored-image?forum=windowsdirectshowdevelopment), but I can't get an answer for it. Please forgive me to post same question on here.

Now I'm creating a virtual camera filter with DirectShow. It's working well on AmCap & GraphEdit.
But when I use it on Skype, Skype shows "mirrored(L-R inversed)" image on setting menu.
At least, It's not for top-down issue. I mean, the "height" isn't minus value.
And then, if I start video calling on Skype, it shows correctly for both of mine and other's.

Additionally, If I choose other UVC web camera, it shows correctly at setting menu. And if I start video calling, my image is mirrored, and other's is correctly.

As the structure of filters are followings;
`class CVCam : public CSource, public ISpecifyPropertyPages`
`class COutPushPin : public CSourceStream, public IAMStreamConfig, public IKsPropertySet`
And CVcam has COutPushPin.

Then, graph structure is followings;
`CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory //It's an OTC web camera`
`->CLSID_MjpegDec`
`->CLSID_SampleGrabber`
`->CLSID_NullRenderer`

How can I correct Skype image? Should I implement some interfaces? Or some kinds of values or flags should I set? If so, please teach me what should I do.

Additionally, this virtual camera is very similar with this project.
https://github.com/diegocr/vcam
And this project has same "mirror" issue.

Comment: I thought it might be Skype's feature to mirror that intentionally, but since they implemented it in their code for some pixel formats only and not for others it might mirror for your camera and not mirror for other. In particular, I saw the mirroring with my virtual device for Lync (Skype for Business) - there was mirroring there which I was sure I did not do myself.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I found an another virtual camera(ASUS Virtual Camera), and the behavior is same as mine. Probably, this behavior is limitation or a bug of Skype. I gave up to fix this issue. Thanks.